# Install mysql workbench community on fedora 23

Tags: fedora, mysql

The mysql-workbench-community package is available for Fedora 22 in the official repos, but unfortunately not yet for Fedora 23.

Trying to install the fc22 version results in mysql-workbench not starting with the error:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs
```

but I don't like installing (outdated) fc22 packages on fc23 anyway.

Is there a way to install/package mysql-workbench myself for fc23 until the package comes officially available from the repos?

Comment: As of today, I was able to get a working workbench by uninstalling mysql-workbench-community then re-installing it.  dnf update/upgrade did not successfully update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79101 No official solution so far except waiting for next release (6.3.6).

I haven't tried but here is a procedure to build from source:
https://gist.github.com/ipernet/a303ae389c3b1f5f2580

Comment: [MySQL Workbench 6.3.6 was released](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlworkbench/entry/mysql_workbench_6_3_6), so it must show up in YUM already.

Answer (score -2):

I better installed HeidiSQL, emulated with wine, coz it is only  for windows.

This is the official pag:
http://www.heidisql.com/

it is really easy to use, it reminds me old Mysql Browser.

i don't like to emulate windows programs, but i couldn't install Emma, or another good Mysql for free.

I use fedora 23.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm aware of other options, but it's not the answer to this question..