# mysql-workbench error while loading shared libraries (libzip.so.2)

Tags: fedora, mysql

I'm trying to use mysql-workbench on my Fedora 23 machine but it fails.
When I try to start it, I get the following message:

```
[daniele@localhost ~]$ mysql-workbench
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libzip is installed:

```
[root@localhost daniele]# dnf reinstall libzip; mysql-workbench
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:18:56 ago on Mon Dec 28 11:40:18 2015.
Abhängigkeiten sind aufgelöst.
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Paket                                            Arch                                             Version                                                  Paketquelle                                      Größe
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Neuinstallieren:
 libzip                                           x86_64                                           1.0.1-2.fc23                                             fedora                                            48 k

Transaktionsübersicht
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================

Gesamte Downloadgröße: 48 k
Ist dies in Ordnung? [j/N] :j
Pakete werden heruntergeladen:
libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                      73 kB/s |  48 kB     00:00    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gesamt                                                                                                                                                                              30 kB/s |  48 kB     00:01     
Transaktionsüberprüfung wird ausgeführt
Transaktionsprüfung war erfolgreich.
Transaktion wird getestet
Transaktionstest war erfolgreich.
Transaktion wird ausgeführt
  Neuinstallieren  : libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                1/2 
  Löschen          : libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                2/2 
  Überprüfung läuft: libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                1/2 
  Überprüfung läuft: libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                2/2 

Reinstalliert:
  libzip.x86_64 1.0.1-2.fc23                                                                                                                                                                                       

Komplett!

/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since I'm a relatively new linux user, this might be nonsense: Could the problem be, that the file doesn't appear anywhere on the computer?

```
[root@localhost /]# du | grep "libzip"
4   ./usr/share/licenses/libzip
```

## Update 2015-12-29

I've installed the libzip version found [here](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/17/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libzip-0.10.1-1.fc17.x86_64.rpm) and it seems to be working. But I get another error:

```
[daniele@localhost ~]$ mysql-workbench
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs
```

According to some research, this error is because of an old mysql-workbench version: [Install mysql workbench community on fedora 23](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241476/install-mysql-workbench-community-on-fedora-23)

But my mysql-workbench version is already the patched one (according to the comment under the only answer) as visible followed by a segmentation fault:

```
[daniele@localhost ~]$ mysql-workbench --version
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.3.6 CE build 511
*** Segmentation fault
```

## Update 2015-12-30

As suggested by Otheus, the sanity check showing the correct versions

```
[root@localhost daniele]# rpm -qi mysql-workbench-community
Name        : mysql-workbench-community
Version     : 6.3.6
Release     : 1.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Di 29 Dez 2015 10:23:19 CET
Group       : Applications/Databases
Size        : 120798819
License     : GPLv2
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Mo 14 Dez 2015 11:32:23 CET, Key ID 8c718d3b5072e1f5
Source RPM  : mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-1.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Do 10 Dez 2015 15:30:31 CET
Build Host  : vilma73.no.oracle.com
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Vendor      : Oracle Corporation
URL         : http://wb.mysql.com
Summary     : A MySQL visual database modeling, administration, development and migration tool
Description :
MySQL Workbench is a unified visual tool for database architects, developers,
and DBAs. MySQL Workbench provides data modeling, SQL development, and
comprehensive administration tools for server configuration, user
administration, backup, and much more. MySQL Workbench is available on
Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.
[root@localhost daniele]# rpm -qf /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost daniele]# ldd /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff62741000)
    libmforms.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce20b5f000)
    liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce208f7000)
    libsqlide.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libsqlide.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce20687000)
    libwbprivate.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1fbb7000)
    libwbpublic.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbpublic.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1ef57000)
    libwbbase.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbbase.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1ed07000)
    libgrt.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libgrt.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1ea0f000)
    libcdbc.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libcdbc.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1e7ef000)
    libwbscintilla.so => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbscintilla.so (0x00007fce1e4ff000)
    libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1e2d7000)
    libmdcanvas.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvas.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1e00f000)
    libmysqlparser.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmysqlparser.so.6.3.6 (0x00007fce1b67f000)
    libmysqlcppconn.so.7 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmysqlcppconn.so.7 (0x00007fce1b35f000)
    libctemplate.so.3 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libctemplate.so.3 (0x00007fce1b0ff000)
    libSM.so.6 => /lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fce1aed7000)
    libICE.so.6 => /lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fce1acb7000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fce1a977000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fce1a75f000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fce1a4af000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce19e1f000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce19b57000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fce19827000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fce195d7000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce193af000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce1902f000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fce18e07000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce18baf000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce1886f000)
    libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 => /lib64/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fce18227000)
    libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 => /lib64/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fce17fd7000)
    libpangomm-1.4.so.1 => /lib64/libpangomm-1.4.so.1 (0x00007fce17da7000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fce17b97000)
    libcairomm-1.0.so.1 => /lib64/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 (0x00007fce1796f000)
    libgiomm-2.4.so.1 => /lib64/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fce175b7000)
    libatkmm-1.6.so.1 => /lib64/libatkmm-1.6.so.1 (0x00007fce17367000)
    libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /lib64/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fce170e7000)
    libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce16edf000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce16cd7000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fce16acf000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fce166ff000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fce16397000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fce16127000)
    libpcrecpp.so.0 => /lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0x00007fce15f17000)
    libzip.so.2 => /lib64/libzip.so.2 (0x00007fce15d07000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fce15aef000)
    libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007fce154c7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fce152a7000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fce1509f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fce14e97000)
    libgnome-keyring.so.0 => /lib64/libgnome-keyring.so.0 (0x00007fce14c6f000)
    libtinyxml.so.0 => /lib64/libtinyxml.so.0 (0x00007fce14a57000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fce1484f000)
    libantlr3c_wb.so => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libantlr3c_wb.so (0x00007fce1462f000)
    libvsqlitepp.so.3 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libvsqlitepp.so.3 (0x00007fce143ff000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /lib64/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007fce1418f000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fce13ef7000)
    libgdal.so.1 => /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libgdal.so.1 (0x00007fce1333f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fce12fb7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fce12caf000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fce12a97000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce126cf000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fce124a7000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fce12297000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fce1205f000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fce11e57000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fce11c3f000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fce119f7000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fce117e7000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fce115df000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fce113cf000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fce111bf000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fce10faf000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fce10da7000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fce10b9f000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fce108f7000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007fce106c7000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fce104bf000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fce102af000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib64/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fce1009f000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fce0fe77000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fce0fc57000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fce0fa4f000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fce0f7e7000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fce0f5df000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fce0f3b7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b45a9f1000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fce0f167000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fce0ee7f000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fce0ebaf000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fce0e97f000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fce0e74f000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fce0e547000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fce0e327000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fce0e11f000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fce0df17000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fce0dd0f000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007fce0daff000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fce0d8f7000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fce0d6ef000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fce0d4e7000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fce0d2df000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fce0d0d7000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fce0cec7000)
    libodbc.so.2 => /lib64/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007fce0cc57000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007fce0ca3f000)
    libjpeg.so.62 => /lib64/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007fce0c7df000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /lib64/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fce0c567000)
    libpng15.so.15 => /lib64/libpng15.so.15 (0x00007fce0c337000)
    libpq.so.5 => /lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fce0c107000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fce0be87000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fce0bc7f000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /lib64/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007fce0ba6f000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib64/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007fce0b85f000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /lib64/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007fce0b647000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib64/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fce0b43f000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fce0b21f000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib64/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fce0b197000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fce0af7f000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fce0ad6f000)
    libjbig.so.2.1 => /lib64/libjbig.so.2.1 (0x00007fce0ab5f000)
    libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fce0a8df000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fce0a48f000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fce0a23f000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fce09fdf000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib64/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007fce09db7000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007fce09b7f000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007fce0994f000)
    libssl3.so => /lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007fce09707000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007fce094df000)
    libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007fce091b7000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fce08f87000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007fce08d7f000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007fce08b77000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007fce08937000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fce0864f000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fce08417000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fce0820f000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fce07fff000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fce07da7000)
    libdw.so.1 => /lib64/libdw.so.1 (0x00007fce07b57000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fce0794f000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fce0773f000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fce07537000)
    libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007fce07317000)
    libelf.so.1 => /lib64/libelf.so.1 (0x00007fce070ff000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fce06ef7000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fce06cbf000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fce06a3f000)
```

Comment: Use `find /usr -name "libzip*"`, and make sure the mysql workbench you have installed is a 64bit version (you only have 64bit libzip installed). To check: `file /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin`.

Comment: @Mat both libzip and mysql-workbench are 64bit: `/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux)` and `/usr/lib64/libzip.so.4`

Comment: Where did you install MySQL workbench from? It is expecting an older libzip version.

Comment: I installed the newest version for Fedora 23 from [mysql.com/downloads/workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Comment: It is an ugly hack, but give it a go. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libzip.so.4 /usr/lib64/libzip.so.2` and start the service.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was trying this in the same moment you suggested it. But it doesn't work. Seems to need that one exact version. `[root@localhost daniele]# mysql-workbench 
Gkr-Message: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs`

Comment: Two errors there. Afaik there seems to be a version related error, and it is complaining about dbus not being installed/running

Comment: First error was because I accidentally executed it as root. I only get the second error. Regardless of the libzip.so version. I am currently using the libzip.so.2 installed from a local rpm. `[daniele@localhost ~]$ mysql-workbench 
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs
`

Comment: Sanity check, please. What's the output of `rpm -qi mysql-workbench-community` and of `rpm -qf /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin` and finally (assuming the above two match versions) of `ldd /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin`

Comment: @Otheus thank you. I've added that to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the wrong version. The `rpm -qi` output shows:

```
mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-1.el7.x86_64
```

This is built for RHEL 7, not Fedora Core 23. What you need is:

```
mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
```

Go back to the download page again and make sure you get the fc23 version. Remove the existing one (with `rpm -e`). Then install the fc23 one. You *should* be good to go. However, your previous steps (ie, libZip) to remedy the problem might now interfere. That is, you might need to uninstall libzip and re-install the canonical FC23 version.

Comment: thank you for saving my life and sorry for the late feedback.